# jqGrid postdata sends null values (mvc3 asp/net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

jqGrid doesn't send postdata to my controller. I tried all provided solutions on stackoverflow, buy apparently I'm making error(s) somewhere. So here is the code:

```
     function refreshGrid() {
        alert('CompanyNamePart=' + $("#CompanyNamePart").val()); // to check if this is correct value
        $("#list").trigger('reloadGrid');
        return false;
    }

    $(function () {
        var grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'json',
            caption: 'Transaction Log',
            postdata: {
                CompanyNamePart: function () { return $("#CompanyNamePart").val(); },
                UsernamePart: function () { return $("#UsernamePart").val(); },
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("GetTransactionLogData")',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Ref.', 'TradeDate', 'Status'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Reference', index: 'Reference', width: '60' },
                { name: 'TradeDate', index: 'TradeDate', width: '70' },
                { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: '80' }
            ],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            height: '100%'
        });
    });
```

On Controller side I have simple code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetTransactionLogData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows,  string CompanyNamePart, string UsernamePart)
        { return Json(null); }
```

and in Debugging mode when I call refreshGrid() by clicking a button I get one alert to confirm me that it reads correctly value of textfield, and after that it refreshes the grid. I receive call of controller, but values for CompanyNamePart and UsernamePart variables are all null, even though I filled them.

I tried another solution for postdata section with another approach, first I created functions that return needed values and put them in postdata section of grid:

```
    function getCompanyNamePartVal() {
        return $("#CompanyNamePart").val();
    }

    function getUsernamePartVal() {
        return $("#UsernamePart").val();
    }

... in jqgrid definition
    postdata: {
                CompanyNamePart: getCompanyNamePartVal(),
                UsernamePart: getUsernamePartVal(),
            },
```

but with no success.

When I checked Firebug, I could see that jqGrid is not sending postdata values:

```
Get Parameters caught by Firebug
_   1340696638960
_search false
nd  1340696638955
page    1
rows    10
sidx    
sord    asc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter is called `postData`, not `postdata`. Don't forget that javascript is a case sensitive language. So try like this:

```
postData: {
    CompanyNamePart: function () { return $("#CompanyNamePart").val(); },
    UsernamePart: function () { return $("#UsernamePart").val(); }
}
```

Also notice that I removed a trailing comma after the `UsernamePart` function that you had in your code and which produces invalid javascript. Some more sensitive browsers might not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/DocumentoBalanza/GetBalanzaEmpresaMes",
        //postData: JSON.stringify(formDataParam),
        postData : {
            id: function () { return formDataParam.id; },
            strDate: function () { return formDataParam.strDate; },
        },
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
```

---

```
public JsonResult GetBalanzaEmpresaMes(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, int id, string strDate)
```

Code OK.